# C code for loading bitmap

Tags: c, image-processing, bitmap, bmp

Does anybody know a good C sample that loads bitmaps and handles all the cases: rle, b/w bitmaps, so on?

Code should be cross-platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using a library like [SDL image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a minimal bmp loader this link will give you all you need to know about the BMP format, data structures and sample code without any library dependency to load:

http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bmp/.

It also contains code to see the loaded BMP in a open gl texture, so pretty much all you need...

Answer (score 1):

Chris Backhouse made a functional little BMP loader (with an eye to using them as OpenGL textures). It's C++, not C, and he admits it's not cross platform. However, it's small and easy to understand, so I thought I'd add the link here:

http://users.ox.ac.uk/~orie1330/bmploader.html

Answer (score 1):

You need some external library to do this (I recommend [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)).  The ImageMagick web site also includes documentation and examples.

Comment: I agree, but if resource usage isn't an issue for your app, it's much easier than rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

Check out for OpenCV Library developed by Intel .

Comment: I definitely recommand opencv too.
I'm using it for a multi touch project, and it's really cool :-)

Comment: Using opencv would be like using a truck to move a glass to the other end of the table. Open CV is a computer vision library, it does reading and writing images on the side.

Answer (score 0):

If you are tied to the BMP file format, it's pretty simple to look at the header yourself and get the pixels.  [See this google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=bmp+file+format).  One of the more interesting matches is [here](http://atlc.sourceforge.net/bmp.html).  The most counter-intuitive part is that every line of pixels is 4-byte aligned.  Also, watch out for compressed BMPs...  (My experience is that many third-party tools have trouble with compressed BMPs, so maybe some libraries you encounter will also..)

If you aren't tied to the BMP file format, I recommend libpng.  The [manual](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html) provides some sample code which is pretty clear.

Comment: I've done basic googling already. Thanks for response though.

Comment: OK.  I'd still encourage you to look at the sample code in the libpng manual, if PNG is an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested you might want to use an external library like SDL. If you want to learn something and do it yourself, see my answer to this very similar question: [Getting RGB values for each pixel from a 24bpp Bitmap for conversion to GBA format in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531268/getting-rgb-values-for-each-pixel-from-a-24bpp-bitmap-in-c/1532386#1532386) where you'll find C code which prints out each pixel, and have a look at the wikipedia page about bmp files, because it's very good.