# C++: Comparing the decimal value in a if statement

Tags: c++, pixel

I am printing out the values of the pixels in a .bmp file. My problem is, if the pixel is not 255 255 255 (white) then I want it to be 0 0 0 (black).

This is the full code: (Yes this is from [Getting RGB values for each pixel from a 24bpp Bitmap for conversion to GBA format in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531268/getting-rgb-values-for-each-pixel-from-a-24bpp-bitmap-in-c))
This works for a 24 bit .bmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma pack(2)


typedef struct
{
    char signature[2];
    unsigned int fileSize;
    unsigned int reserved;
    unsigned int offset;
} BmpHeader;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int headerSize;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned short planeCount;
    unsigned short bitDepth;
    unsigned int compression;
    unsigned int compressedImageSize;
    unsigned int horizontalResolution;
    unsigned int verticalResolution;
    unsigned int numColors;
    unsigned int importantColors;

} BmpImageInfo;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char red;
    //unsigned char reserved; Removed for convenience in fread; info.bitDepth/8 doesn't seem to work for some reason
} Rgb;


int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

        FILE *inFile;
        BmpHeader header;
        BmpImageInfo info;
        Rgb *palette;
        int i = 0;

        printf( "Opening file %s for reading.\n", argv[1] );

        inFile = fopen( argv[1], "rb" );
        if( !inFile ) {
                printf( "Error opening file %s.\n", argv[1] );
            return -1;
        }

        if( fread(&header, 1, sizeof(BmpHeader), inFile) != sizeof(BmpHeader) ) {
                printf( "Error reading bmp header.\n" );
            return -1;
        }

        if( fread(&info, 1, sizeof(BmpImageInfo), inFile) != sizeof(BmpImageInfo) ) {
                printf( "Error reading image info.\n" );
            return -1;
        }

        if( info.numColors > 0 ) {
                printf( "Reading palette.\n" );
                palette = (Rgb*)malloc(sizeof(Rgb) * info.numColors);
                if( fread(palette, sizeof(Rgb), info.numColors, inFile) != (info.numColors * sizeof(Rgb)) ) {
                        printf( "Error reading palette.\n" );
                return -1; // error
                }
        }

        printf( "Opening file %s for writing.\n", argv[2] );
        FILE *outFile = fopen( argv[2], "wb" );
        if( !outFile ) {
                printf( "Error opening outputfile.\n" );
                return -1;
        }
        Rgb *pixel = (Rgb*) malloc( sizeof(Rgb) );
        int read, j;
        for( j=0; j<info.height; j++ ) {
                printf( "------ Row %d\n", j+1 );
                read = 0;
                for( i=0; i<info.width; i++ ) {
                        if( fread(pixel, 1, sizeof(Rgb), inFile) != sizeof(Rgb) ) {
                                printf( "Error reading pixel!\n" );
                                return -1;
                        }
                        read += sizeof(Rgb);
                        if (pixel->red != 255 || pixel->green != 255 || pixel->blue != 255)
                            printf( "Pixel %d: 0 0 0\n", i+1, );
                        else
                            printf( "Pixel %d: %3d %3d %3d\n", i+1, pixel->red, pixel->green, pixel->blue );
                        /*if (pixel->red != 255 || pixel->green != 255 || pixel->blue != 255)
                            printf ("Pixel %d: 0 0 0\n", i+1);
                        else
                            printf( "Pixel %d: 255 255 255\n", i+1);*/

                }
                if( read % 4 != 0 ) {
                        read = 4 - (read%4);
                        printf( "Padding: %d bytes\n", read );
                        fread( pixel, read, 1, inFile );
                }
        }

        printf( "Done.\n" );
        fclose(inFile);
        fclose(outFile);

        printf( "\nBMP-Info:\n" );
        printf( "Width x Height: %i x %i\n", info.width, info.height );
        printf( "Depth: %i\n", (int)info.bitDepth );

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with comparing with a numeric constant (`pixel->red != 255` etc)? Or does your real code require you to compare with arbitrary string values?

Comment: So what? If the pixel is white, you print "255 255 255", otherwise you print "0 0 0"?

Comment: Don't you think it might be useful to know what types red/green/blue are?

Comment: It'd be good if you allowed hexadecimal too (e.g. 000000 or FFFFFF). Also if these are truly integers, then just use `strtol()` then compare the integers.

Comment: Edited to add a little more information. Sorry i thought it would be a simpler question than it is. Just wanted to know if there was a %d equivalence in if statements

Comment: @LiverpoolFTW - you want `pixel->read != 255`, but that's not important now. Are you really allocating exactly **one** `Rgb` with `malloc`? If so, please show us your `fread`; I think you have a buffer overflow.

Comment: I've tried your code and it prints out lots of "255 255 255" and "0 0 0", nothing else, as expected...

Comment: OMG! i hate it when this happens. Gotta figure out why it wont work on my comp then. EDIT: Word to the wise people. re-compile your programs when you make changes! Sorry for the troubles :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pixel's RGB values are probably integers, not strings:

```
if (pixel->red != 255 || pixel->green != 255 || pixel->blue != 255)
    printf ("Pixel %d: 0 0 0\n", i+1);
else
    printf( "Pixel %d: %3d %3d %3d\n", i+1, pixel->red, pixel->green, pixel->blue );
```

Since you want to print "255 255 255" if the pixel is white, or "0 0 0" otherwise, it's simpler to do this:

```
if (pixel->red != 255 || pixel->green != 255 || pixel->blue != 255)
    printf ("Pixel %d: 0 0 0\n", i+1);
else
    printf( "Pixel %d: 255 255 255\n", i+1);
```

Comment: Tried this with no luck. also tried with single quotes too. Also ya, that would be simpler to do it that way but it should work the same and later i will have to do it where i need the different colors for the second screen the image will be on this is colored.

Comment: How did you fail? Compiler error? You didn't get the expected output?

Comment: No change in output, still puts the value of the pixel even if its not 255 255 255

Comment: @LiverpoolFTW - if you have copied the 2nd example, then it is *impossible* to have printed the value of the pixel.

Comment: Provide a full, compilable code. You are surely doing something wrong somewhere else. If your `pixel` variable contains a valid pixel, then it should work. Try printing the pixel's values, and then execute that if statement and compare the output.

Comment: Using your second example i still got the same output which was really really weird. I edited original post with full code

Comment: Are you sure it compiled after you changed it. Try putting a printf("Version2\n") at the top and ensuring that appears in the output.